# Detecting horizontal round edges in color images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I'm trying to detect areas that contain a top portion of an oval shape in a color image.

Here are some examples I drew:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8MUh.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNqN2.jpg

How would you accomplish this? I'm inexperienced in image processing, but I'm willing to read and learn. I'm mainly using OpenCV with C++ but I can use other libraries as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the thing you ask is a kind of big problem. In the real world images, you will need to find every oval shape, distinguish which has top (till what angle you tolerate and consider up ?). Then you need to segment those shapes very well so you can find areas with top portion oval shaped objects.

However, if you need to find simpler images like in the example, but still a more general approach, you may first get edges  by using any edge detection (for example Canny). Then, use Hough Transform for curves and ellipses. But I don't think there is function or library for that. So you may need implement your own Hough Transform. For that you must decide what exactly you mean by oval top. For your two images, if you successfully find oval top, just get the area under it. But to get more general you may want to segment shape under it with more sophisticated approach.

For Hough Transform; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Circle_Detection_Process
and for using it with ellipses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_Hough_transform

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a function to detect circles at opencv.

Use [hough transform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles) with low parameter2 -cause you should detect the circle with given only its top.

Another way should be as such;

1- low pass filter (gaussian blur, search inside opencv doc)

2- color filter -optional (use your object's color if you know it, otherwise try to obtain the color from pixel(image.width/2 , 0)

3- canny edge detection (again, refer to the doc)

4- find contours (again, refer to the doc)

5- if you have a contour having preferably big area and including pixel(image.width/2 , 0) -you will use pointPolygonTest here- then you have a blob at the bottom.

6- to detect if this blob is "oval" is a big issue; but you can do some filtering using properties of "ovality";

- oval curves have 1 and only 1 peak point. There should be only 1 contour pixel having maximum height.
- any 3 point of an oval curve cannot represent a line. This is not hard to implement, but complex for an algorithm.

Comment: As I know circle detector in opencv can't detect ellipse shapes.  As their mathematical definition will be different ? sorry I am not keen on OpenCV

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simpler approach than the Hough transform for circles.
From the images above, I see that the oval has a uniform color while the rest of the 
image does not.

1. Choose a proper color space (possibly HSV)
2. Take the gray-scale as the hue or saturation - these will describe the colors in the image (not the intensity of the pixels)
3. Calculate the gradient of (2)
4. Pixels with gradient = 0 belong to the oval

Comment: Although this approach could help for these two images, problem is not "I want to find this two uniform colored objects in these photos which has non-uniform color background", it would be cheating for success in database and if you just change colors then what would happen ?

Comment: Well, it's only 'cheating' if the solution suffers from over-fitting the training set and if it cannot be generalized to the entire data-set. Changing colors will change the hue and saturation but should not adversely affect the gradient (of the hue\saturation).

Comment: By changing colors, I mean make shape with changing colors and background with a color like opaque gray

Answer (score 0):

For ellipse detection, you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603209/image-processing-for-quality-control/16604197#16604197). The two methods are based on the hough transform, and can be tuned easily if required.